# Refering to vector element using string and int variables

Tags: r

```
NAME<-"a";
i<-2;
a<-c(0,1);
```

how can I change the i-th element (i is a variable:integer) of the vector NAME (NAME is a variable:string)?

```
as.name(NAME)[i] doesnt work
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly encourage you to rethink your code; there are often better, more "R-like" ways to do things where this type of operation usually isn't required. But

```
assign(NAME, '[<-'(get(NAME),i,5))
```

or maybe

```
eval(substitute(x[i]<-5, list(x=as.name(NAME))))
```

could work. This will change element 2 to a 5. A better design might be to have the vectors you want to dynamically change be in a named list.

```
dd <- list( 
    a = c(0,1)
)
NAME<-"a";
i<-2;
dd[[NAME]][i]<-5
dd$a
```